# transaction throughput with incomplete keys?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

According to the docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities "There is a write throughput limit of about one transaction per second within a single entity group"

Does this apply to incomplete keys, such that using incomplete keys in a transaction will limit it to only one transaction?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean incomplete keys as in you are letting the system generate the id, then and it is in an entity group then the same rate limit to writes to that entity group.

If it's in a different entity group then no.

Remember the rate limit is per entity group, irrespective of how the keys are generated.

Comment: So if a transaction creates a new entity using an incomplete key (i.e. the only operation on that entity is a "put"), then such a transaction can be run multiple times per second- but if that transaction creates that entity using an incomplete key and then issues another call on that entity (i.e. an additional "put" aside for the first creation), then such a transaction is limited to one per second?

Comment: One transaction commit is allowed per second per entity-group. As Tim said, it is irrelevant if you used an incomplete key, i.e. the datastore assigned the ID, or if your app code provided an ID. How often you "put" an entity during the transaction is also irrelevant for this limitation (it just slows down your app). If your new entity object has no parent, and no children, it is isolated in its own entity-group, so you can perform a transactional put on this object every second. Also see http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.de/2015/08/Introduction-to-data-models-in-Cloud-Datastore.html